# XSLT is working only Firefox

Tags: javascript, xslt

Im new to XSLT. I am getting a XML file from return value of ECHO from PHP.

Then I try to transform to XSL but it only works in Firefox.

When I run the Javascript debugger from Chrome it says
:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function maintenance.js:30
>   getData

[Added:  the OP eventually noted that line 30 of maintenance.js reads:

```
function generateReport() { 
  xHRObject.open("GET", "getXML.php", rue); 
  xHRObject.onreadystatechange = getData; //this is where i get debug error in chrome
  xHRObject.send(null); 
}
```

I have broken this into multiple lines for legibility.]

But when I run firebug with same code in Firefox no error and can get the result I want.

```
var xhr = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function getData()
{
    if ((xhr.readyState == 4) &&(xhr.status == 200))
    {
        if (window.ActiveXObject)
        { 
            var xml = xhr.responseXML;
            var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xsl.async = false; xsl.load("abc.xsl");
            var transform = xml.transformNode(xsl);
            var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
            frame.innerHTML = transform;
        }

        else
        {
             var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
              xslStylesheet = document.implementation.createDocument("", "doc", null);
              xslStylesheet.async = false;
              xslStylesheet.load("abc.xsl"); 
              xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);
              xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
              var fragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
              document.getElementById("frame").innerHTML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(fragment);

        }
    }
}

function test()
{
  xhr.open("GET", "getXML.php", true);    
  xhr.onreadystatechange = data;
  xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: How does line 30 with `getData` look exactly in the code when Chrome gives the error?

Comment: Nothing. Nothing happens with that code both IE and Chrome but it works in Firefox only.

Comment: I think the error message `maintenance.js:30 getData` says there is a problem in line 30 of `maintenance.js` with a variable or identifier or function `getData`, at least show us the exact line for which Chrome gives the error message.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function maintenance.js:30 getData This is the exactly what Chrome says. It's Ajax so the getData function will be called several times till response is ok. When I change the line, like getData(); then it will be called only once which isnt what I expect

Comment: Yes, but please then show us that line 30 of `maintenance.js`.

Comment: function generateReport()
{
  xHRObject.open("GET", "getXML.php", true);    
  xHRObject.onreadystatechange = getData;
  xHRObject.send(null);
}

Comment: not much things to check out yea? i can't find any way..

Comment: You seem not to be showing us the definition of `getData` -- is there one?  Or is `getData` a typo / naming error for the function `data`?  [Did you *look* at the error message?   Did you consider that it might be trying to tell you something?  Did you *think* about what it is telling you?]

Comment: Hey mate. I found out the problem! The problem was browsers... IE11 and Chrome latest one. The code works older versions of each browser. Thanks anyway.